# UItableview inside one of the UItableviewController static cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableviewController with 2 sections and each one have 1 custom cell. On the second static cell, I have dropped a UITableview and implemented the delegates accordingly.

Code snippet.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.activityTable)  { // dynamic table
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 2;
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     if (tableView == self.activityTable) { // dynamic tableview
         return [self.fetchActivityController.fetchedObjects count];
     }else {
         return 1;  //static tableview
     }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (tableView == self.activityTable) {

        if ([self.fetchActivityController.fetchedObjects count] == 0)
            return nil;

        ADNetworkCell *cell=[self.activityTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ADNetworkCell class])];
        ADActivity* activityObj = (ADActivity*)[self.fetchActivityController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ADUser* nUser = [activityObj networkAgent];
        [cell configWithAgent:nUser withActivity:[activityObj activity]];
        cell.activityText.delegate=self;
        return cell;
    }else {   // static tableview code

        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (tableView == self.activityTable) {
        return 95.0f;
    } else {
        // The height of the 2nd static cell should be size of tableview with dynamic cell.
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            return 95 * [self.activityArray count];
        }
    }
    return 44.0f;
}
```

## Its crashing

> uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d0b8f45 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010c60bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
>
>   2   CoreFoundation 0x000000010cfa7b14 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 164
>
>   3   UIKit 0x000000010b179516 -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 160
>
>   4   UIKit 0x000000010ae4929b -[UITableViewController tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 65
>
>   5   UIKit 0x000000010abb7325 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2226
>
>   6   UIKit 0x000000010ab15c10 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
>   7   UIKit 0x000000010abb6a5a -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 475
>
>   8   UIKit 0x000000010abc1e58 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 828
>
>   9   UIKit 0x000000010abc1f3f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>
>   10  UIKit 0x000000010ab97307 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
>
>   11  UIKit 0x000000010abcad1c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
>
>   12  UIKit 0x000000010abb2884 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 223
>
>   13  UIKit 0x000000010ab20e40 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
>
>   14  QuartzCore 0x000000010a7ec59a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>
>   15  QuartzCore 0x000000010a7e0e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>
>   16  QuartzCore 0x000000010a7e0cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>
>   17  QuartzCore 0x000000010a7d5475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>
>   18  QuartzCore 0x000000010a802c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
>
>   19  UIKit 0x000000010aa66ca4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7329
>
>   20  CoreFoundation 0x000000010cfe5011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>   21  CoreFoundation 0x000000010cfdaf3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>   22  CoreFoundation 0x000000010cfda3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>   23  CoreFoundation 0x000000010cfd9e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>   24  GraphicsServices 0x000000010e733ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>   25  UIKit 0x000000010aa6c30d UIApplicationMain + 171
>   26  Agentdesks 0x000000010863164f main + 111
>   27  libdyld.dylib 0x000000010d59c92d start + 1    28  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: By looking at the stack, it seems that there are error about array count in `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` function. if you are implementing this delegate, could you please also post its code?

Comment: No such delegate, Its internally hitting this function.